# discuz! X 3.0 bbcode and attach preg_replace

Tags: php, javascript

```
$tid = $_GET['tid'];
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/common/class/class.thread.php';
$thread = new getThread;
$getThread = $thread->get_content($tid);
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/common/class/class.thread.php';
$thread = new getThread;
$getThread = $thread->get_content($tid);
$attachmentTable = substr($tid, -1);
$tdatabase = new threadDatabase();
$tdatabase->query('SELECT * FROM mycms_forum_attachment_' . $attachmentTable .  ' WHERE tid = :tid ORDER BY aid DESC');
$tdatabase->bind(':tid', $tid);
$attachmentContainer = $tdatabase->resultset();
print_r($attachmentContainer);

//following is content , it pull from db($getThread)
//main content start
[attach]42[/attach]


[align=left][attach]53[/attach][/align]
content bla bla bla                      content bla bla bla
[align=left][attach]52[/attach][/align]
content bla bla bla


content bla bla bla
//main content end

//following is attachment file
[0] => Array ( [aid] => 53 [tid] => 32 [pid] => 32 [uid] => 1 [filesize] => 152633 [attachment] => 201305/22/142619h42az34077hhra0p.jpg [width] => 1080 ) 
[1] => Array ( [aid] => 52 [tid] => 32 [pid] => 32 [uid] => 1 [filesize] => 89015 [attachment] => 201305/22/142618wx3njhgf3n883zxr.jpg [width] => 1080 )
```

how do i use preg_replace to change the [attach]53[/attach] to be

the src take from the array where aid=53 due to it is [attach]53[/attach] and width too

i had try the following , but get error and i know is wrong to do in this way , because $attachmentContainer[$1]['attachment'] is start with 0 and 53 is not exist , get stucked and no idea to do.

```
$threadContainer = preg_replace('/\[attach\](.*?)\[\/attach\]/i', '<img src="' . $attachmentContainer[$1]['attachment'] . '" width="' . $attachment[$1]['width'] . '" />', $getThread['message']);
```

my question:
do it in javascript or php better?
how do i preg_replace all the [attach][/attach] with correct src and width store at db ?
and check the content , how do i handle these "space" to 
 for line break?

i'm trying to pull discuz! x3.0 thread content directly from db.

THANKS for teaching!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you want, but from your last chunk of code I'd say you need [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), because `$attachmentContainer[$1]['attachment']` should not evaluate before the `preg_replace` is called.

So, your last chunk of code should look like this:

```
$threadContainer = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\[attach\](.*?)\[\/attach\]/i',
    function ($matches) {
        return '<img src="' . $attachmentContainer[$matches[1]]['attachment'] . '" width="' . $attachment[$matches[1]]['width'] . '" />';
    },
    $getThread['message']
);
```

Comment: hmm...is the $matches[1] will matched the aid ?

Comment: Yes. I gave you the link to the documentation, so you can see for yourself how this works.